# python pyautogui module are not support bangla text

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

Here is my python code. I am trying to write something in Bangla text using pyautoGUI but unfortunately, it's not working.

```
    import time
    import pyautogui
    
    time.sleep(2)
    text = "হ্যালো,"
    
    pyautogui.typewrite(text)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui doesn't seem to allow some characters without giving a Unicode hex string but I found an easier way by putting it in your clipboard.

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time

time.sleep(5)

# Store our string to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy("হ্যালো")
# Hotkey the paste command
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

This works about the same as typewrite just using a paste command instead of sending it like a keyboard (one charachter at a time)

```
# Output to typed
হ্যালো
```